# Python Multiple Strings to Tuples

Tags: python

Hi everyone I wonder if you can help with my problem.

I am defining a function which takes a string and converts it into 5 items in a tuple. The function will be required to take a number of strings, in which some of the items will vary in length. How would I go about doing this as using the indexes of the string does not work for every string.

As an example -

I want to convert a string like the following:

```
Doctor E212 40000 Peter David Jones
```

The tuple items of the string will be:

```
Job(Doctor), Department(E212), Pay(40000), Other names (Peter David), Surname (Jones)
```

However some of the strings have 2 other names where others will have just 1.

How would I go about converting strings like this into tuples when the other names can vary between 1 and 2?

I am a bit of a novice when it comes to python as you can probably tell ;)

Comment: How would *you* go about it, and in what way(s) does it not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Python 3, you can just `split()` and  use ["catch-all" tuple unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) with `*`:

```
>>> string = "Doctor E212 40000 Peter David Jones"
>>> job, dep, sal, *other, names = string.split()
>>> job, dep, sal, " ".join(other), names
('Doctor', 'E212', '40000', 'Peter David', 'Jones')
```

Alternatively, you can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), e.g. something like this:

```
>>> m = re.match(r"(\w+) (\w+) (\d+) ([\w\s]+) (\w+)", string)
>>> job, dep, sal, other, names = m.groups()
>>> job, dep, sal, other, names
('Doctor', 'E212', '40000', 'Peter David', 'Jones')
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, I tried implementing the first method however it did not work when used in a function like the following: (where 'x' is a string)                                                                                                  `def strTup(x):
    payR, dep, sal, *other, surn = x.split()
    payR, dep, sal, " ".join(other), surn`

Comment: Sorry for the layout of the code, Its not easy in comments lol, please could you tell me how to get this working so that it returns a tuple like in the above example, thanks :)

Comment: Well,you have to `return` the tuple; in my code I just echoed it in the interactive shell. In your function, use `return payR, dep, sal, " ".join(other), surn`.

Comment: I was having some trouble implementing it and getting it to return the output when ran, however I have sorted that now

Comment: @RJB Good to hear that. Just drop a comment if you have any more troubles.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)